# calculating position of a point knowing two reference lengths

Tags: vector-spaces, coordinate-systems, polar-coordinates, triangulation

[image]

Hi,
I would like to know if there is a way to calculate a unique position for Point A knowing the lengths l1 and l2 which are variable string lengths.  Point A can move within the range shown below.  2D equations are fine but in reality the strings have a slight 3D components as well.

So if there is a general form of equations for l1,l2 to be 3D vectors in space, that would be better.  Or do you need a 3rd length, l3?

Thank you!

Mick

Comment: Are the connection points of $l1$ and $l2$ at those line segments fixed? If so, you have a triangle with three known sides and everything about the triangle can be found.

Comment: yes, the connection points of l1 and l2 are fixed.  You are right!  The point between l1 and l2 is also fixed so three lengths of the triangle are known (but no angles are measured).  However, there is a small 3D element to consider.  Actually, Point A is fixed to a stick that is rotating below on the ground.  so it moves in a arc-like shape.